shadcn/ui component to display formState error
With shadcn/ui, the FormMessage is used to display validation error in form field. Is there a component to display the error from form.formState.errors?
  const form = useForm({
    resolver: zodResolver(RegistrationSchema),
  });

  // form.formState.errors

